# javascript textbox not to allow special characters

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have a problem in validating Textbox in which I have to enter time.
 in that only the symbol 
":"  is allowed,
text also should not allow.

how to do this..

and

I am following the pattern `/^\d{1,2}:\d{2}$/`

if anyone help me would be appreciated.

thanx in advance.

Comment: That should work, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try and use following regular expression for validating HH:MM time format

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

try below pattern:

```
/^\d{2,}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/
```